Consul list services, how to filter by service name?
I'm using the http call curl -s --get http://MyConsulURL/v1/catalog/services to list services like so:
"MYSVC": [],
"MYSVC1": ["mytag1","mytag2"],
"MYSVC2": ["mytag3","mytag3"],
"OTHERSVC": [],
...snip...

My question is, is there a way to use the filter option on the http call to return only the services with name containing the string "MYSVC"?
PS. I know I can pipe it into a jq query, but I'm trying to filter the results before they get returned.

This seems very similar to this answer from 2021:
Consul API, Retrieve services instances list from all nodes
Executive summary:
Consul doesn't have this feature.  The only solution is to fetch all services, then filter the list yourself
